# Flutter 2.5 on Mac M1 - symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, apple-silicon

I have a flutter project which uses a plugin written by a colleague (which is not there anymore). I develop on Mac M1.
Since I upgraded to Flutter 2.5, I cannot start my app on iOS in Debug-Mode.

It says
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When I remove the dependency to this plugin, everything works.
I tried the following:

- Change architecture-settings in xcode
- Delete derived data
- Delete podfile
- Upgrade all dependencies
- run pod repo-update

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks!